# How to connect ASP.Net Core to a SQL Server Docker container on Mac

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-mac

I am developing an ASP.Net core MVC application using Visual Studio 2017 on Mac. However, I am facing some problems to connect to an instance of SQL Server that is running on a Docker container.

This is the connection string I'm using:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "myCustomConnString": "Server=localhost;Database=myDataBase;User Id=sa;Password=myPassw0rd;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

And this is the error I am getting:

> Cannot authenticate using Kerberos. Ensure Kerberos has been
>   initialized on the client with 'kinit' and a Service Principal Name
>   has been registered for the SQL Server to allow Kerberos
>   authentication. ErrorCode=InternalError,
>   Exception=Interop+NetSecurityNative+GssApiException: GSSAPI operation
>   failed with error -  An unsupported mechanism was requested (unknown
>   mech-code 0 for mech unknown).

Using SQL Operation Studio, Azure Data Studio and/ or Visual Studio Code and passing the same parameters I can connect to the docker instance of SQL Server. But not when running the ASP.Net core app. So, I'm not sure if I am missing any additional parameter for the connection string.

Does anyone have try this before?

Regards!

Comment: Found how to connect to the Docker instance of SQL Server. I had to set up the Trusted_Connection=false. After that I was able to connect when running my ASP.Net core app.

Comment: Thanks! I wasted so much time on this one and that fixed it!

Answer (score 40):

I know that @MikePR 's comment serves as the answer, but I wanted to provide a more complete answer for the issue I had. I could not get `dotnet ef database` commands to execute evan after using the connection string with `Trusted_Connection=false`. With the help of [this article](https://kunzleigh.com/running-a-net-core-app-with-sql-server-on-osx-using-docker/), I was able to use this connection string:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "myCustomConnString": "Server=localhost,1433\\Catalog=myDatabase;Database=myDatabase;User=username;Password=MYSecurePWD;"
  }
```

Now, my migrations run against the SQL Server in the docker container. Note that the article did not include using `Trusted_Connection=false`. I assume that false is the default.

Answer (score 16):

I got the same issue, and it works simply by deleting
**Trusted_Connection=True;**
from the connection string

Answer (score 5):

Solved mine by setting **`Trusted_Connection=False`**

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve mine by removing Trusted_Connection

Answer (score 3):

I ran the connection string as follows and it worked

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DevConnection": "Server=localhost,1433;Database=TarjetaCreditoDB;User Id=sa;Password=myPassw0rd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Below string worked for me.

```
 Server=sql-server-db,1433;Database=EMP_DB_V2;User=SA;Password=Test_pwd@786;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I ran the connection string as follows and it worked

```java
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost,1433; Database=ERPDb; User=sa; Password =*****; Trusted_Connection=false; TrustServerCertificate=true;"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine by removing `Integrated Security=true;`.